# Regex do not match "ave" if end of line

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse addresses however I am running into the issue of streets ending with "ave" being matched because the word avenue needs to be matched as a street name as well.

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/AvNKAV/2)

```
(?<=[\d\w] )((?!\s(court|ct|street|st|drive|dr|lane|ln|road|rd|blvd|cir|trl|trail|crossing|xing|pl|place|ave\s|cv|cove|trce|trace|mnr|way|loop|bnd|bend|lndg|landing|path|pkwy|parkway|pass|rdg|ridge|vw)).)*
```

For example:

```
123 testing blah ave
MATCH: testing blah ave
EXPECTED: testing blah

123 avenue d
MATCH: avenue d
EXPECTED: avenue d
```

Simply adding a space to the end of "ave" corrects the match however it wont have a space.

Comment: By adding the `\s` you are insisting that there be some type of whitespace after `ave`.

Comment: I know its incorrect but it was a quick work around however im hoping for a better solution

Comment: Are u looking for regex to match the **avenue** but **ave**?

Comment: @TaylorReed In that case I'm confused why `ave` is the only string where the `\s` was added.  Why not onto all of the other options?

Comment: This is a completely hopeless approach to matching street addresses; ANY of those supposed ending words could legitimately appear in the middle of the street name.  For example, "Ridge Path Road" is an actual street in Polkton, NC.

Comment: @Salman correct, if you were to type 123 avenue ave it should only match the word "avenue" and stop.

Comment: @huck_cussler the reason I added the \s is because an address like "1608 N AVENUE R" only matches "N"

Comment: What happens if you replace `\s` with `$`?

Comment: That actually seems to have worked. Thanks @huck_cussler!

Answer (score 1):

Use `ave\b` instead of `ave\s` . If *ave* is followed by a space, they would be of the same effect; but if *ave* is followed by end-of line, `\b` will still match while `\s` won't (it requires a space to really be present).